# Is it a bad idea to create a class which will only have one instance?

Tags: design, design-patterns

Is it bad coding practice/design to make a class which will only be instantiated once?

I have some variables and functions that can be grouped together under a class to "look good" (for a lack of a better description) since they are somewhat related, but they can just be global variables and global functions.

(Btw, I am using JavaScript, AngularJS, Express, MongoDB.)

Comment: Perhaps you need a Singleton class. However it is bad idea to bind in a class, things that are not related properly.

Comment: Singleton pattern is bad. Single instance sometimes is the correct solution.

Comment: Neither "Singleton" nor "Single instance" is a good solution for grouping "just somewhat related" global things together - when I hear such a description, I take this always as a warning signal. But to give you a serious answer, you should tell us some examples of the variables and functions you are going to group together (with their real names and meaning).

Comment: The Singleton pattern is not bad necessarily.  It's only that it tends to be overused.

Comment: Is it even technically possible to enforce a Singleton in JavaScript?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A single instance for a class makes sense if the object represents a single resource, like a ethernet connexion or the operating system task manager for instance.

Functions are put in a class only if they act on the variables of instances of that class, otherwise the maintainer will be confused about the intention of that class.

Usually, a good reason exists why your app has global variables. Try to find the common purpose of them and design a class around this purpose. It will not only make the design clear, but your mind as well.

Comment: +1, but I would like to add: "if the only common purpose is that those variables *are* global, better leave them in different classes."

Answer (score 14):

**There is no problem with writing a class that ends being instanced only once.**

If putting some variables and functions together within a class makes sense, has semantic value or makes the code simpler to read and manipulate, then so be it, maintainers will be thankful.

**What can be very wrong though, is to enforce uniqueness from within.**

Many people tend to fire the singleton pattern as soon as they think they'll only need one instance of something. See for example how you haven't described your context in depth, yet most answers already suggest you to use a singleton. And then the design might be screwed because if you need another instance at some point for whatever reason, the class will prevent you from doing it without changing a lot of code.

So as a conclusion, one instance is fine, but make sure to know whether:

1. you **only need one** instance, or
2. you **cannot have more than one** instance (a very, very rare case in my experience).

Comment: re: #2, I don't think this is ever valid. Even if your object is a NuclearPowerStationCentralCommandController and you will only ever own one nuclear power station, you're not seriously telling me you don't have a MockNuclearPowerStationCentralCommandController for testing, are you?

Comment: A more serious but less obvious problem is if you need to have a slightly different implementation of the Singleton, you can't in most languages, because the way you get the Singleton is to go directly to it, rather than have the instance passed in.

Comment: @Phoshi: If only one of something can ever exist, then code can use it without having to hold a reference.  If multiple instances are allowed to exist, then consumers will have to hold references to them.  Not only does this add to the object's storage requirement, but consumers will no longer be able to assume that other consumers will hold a reference to the same object.  This adds considerable complexity.  If the complexity will end up being necessary, it's better to add it sooner rather than later, but if it's not necessary, it may be best avoided.

Comment: @supercat: Adding one reference's worth of memory usage is utterly irrelevant for the overwhelming majority of cases, I don't think that's at all a good reason to avoid DI. You are right that you can't assume everyone has the same instance any more--you shouldn't, that shouldn't matter. It doesn't matter if everyone has a different instance so long as the semantics of the interface hold. Anyway, like I said, you're never going to have only one instance. You have at least one more for testing, and do you really want to risk the assumption your requirements won't ever change?

Comment: @Phoshi: The memory usage isn't the issue; the issue is that one adds another way in which objects can differ.  Consider, for example, what it means for the items in two instances of `Dictionary<TKey,KTValue>` to be distinct.  If all instances of a `Dictionary<TKey,KTValue>` instance use the same `IEqualityComparer`, there's no ambiguity, but if they can use different comparators that define different equivalence relations, I don't know that it's possible to sensibly define `a.ContentsDistinctFrom(b)` to always equal `b.ContentsDistinctFrom(a)`.

Comment: @supercat: That's an issue in the equality functions of KTValue, not an issue with DI. Your equality function shouldn't be checking things like injected dependencies, they should simply be checking the important object state. I don't see that as a real problem--undefined equality check is a reference equality, and you would never define an equality check to include that dependency. It won't happen unless somebody *makes* it happen.

Comment: @Phoshi: A dictionary shouldn't care about its key-objects' states beyond what the passed-in `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` says about them. Some implementations of `Dictionary<String,String>` would consider "ABC" and "Abc" as identical keys; some would consider them distinct. That's a useful ability, but adding it complicates questions like whether two dictionaries contain any items in common, or whether one dictionary contains all the items of another. If two dictionaries use the same equality-comparer, such questions are easy, but even testing *that* is difficult.

Comment: @supercat: Each implementation of the interface is responsible for checking equality. There's no reason why two separate implementations couldn't consider each other equal if such a thing had reasonable semantics, otherwise you wouldn't want them equal anyway. I don't see how it's a problem.

Comment: @Phoshi: The issue of comparator equality drifted off my main point: if all dictionaries that use the same key type, use the same comparator, then code doesn't need to consider the possibility of trying to act upon two dictionaries with the same key type, but different comparators.  Allowing the comparator to be specified on a per-instance basis compels code to handle many tricky cases which could not have occurred if the comparison method were determined by the key type.

Comment: @supercat: Ah! I see, I was misunderstanding your point there. Yes, in that case it would be weird to consider equality a "dependency" but you could certainly do it. If you needed that kind of semantics, though, wouldn't it be beneficial to do it? DI in general follows the same basic rule as any indirection. It works if you don't /need/ to know what exactly is happening, just that it is. You don't need to know where your data comes from or where it goes, just that the right things happen in response.

Comment: @Phoshi: Being able to specify equality comparators on a per-instance basis can certainly be useful.  My point was that allowing it to be specified per-instance rather than globally imposes a *major* cost in complexity.  If one is not prepared to shoulder the costs of allowing something to be specified per-instance, having a per-instance field or property wouldn't be so much a YAGNI as a YWBATUIEIYEUWI (You Wouldn't Be Able To Use It Even IF You End Up Wanting It).

Comment: @supercat: Going back to the original point, then, using a singleton isn't a free action either, and you shoulder the costs in terms of inflexibility and difficulty of correctness checking.

Comment: @Phoshi: Almost any decision will have an associated cost; sometimes adding complexity in one place can ease complexity elsewhere, and sometimes it can make it worse.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it bad coding practice/design to make a class which will only be instantiated once?

No, even if only instantiated once, you need a class for it. But don't suppose you will *always* only need one instance, now and in the future.

Suppose you make a game, and you have a player class:

```
class Player {
    ...
}
```

You will instantiate one player class in your game, and use always the same object. Nothing wrong with it.

However, don't make a Singleton out of it! Today you design your game and think "Well, it will *always* be a one-player game. I will use a Singleton for my Player". But in version 2, you may want to implement multiplayer - and then you are getting into trouble. You will have to rewrite and adapt a lot of code, because your design does not support instantiating multiple players.

The same is with caches. Or loggers. Or network interfaces. Today, you think you will only need one, always, for sure. But in a future version you need to add a second. Be aware of this situation.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking two questions in one.

1. No, there's nothing bad having a class that will only have one instance.
2. Grouping variables and methods in a class without  a real reason for it is bad design.

Answer (score 1):

There are singleton classes and that is a common design pattern.

There are also classes that never get instantiated. If you have functions that DO NOT operate on any persistent state (e.g., they take the input and transform it), you can usually use a static method. In some languages (like Java) these static methods would be declared in a class, but the class itself will never be instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

The singleton pattern is common. It allows you to enforce single instance of class.

But for some it is too common, so it becomes an anti-pattern. The reason for this is because it is practically same as global state. And any global state is hard to mock and test and hard to debug. But at the same time, having to explicitly pass this one instance everywhere in your code can cause code to bloat up a lot. But this will make you think about proper architecture. If bunch of classes use this one singleton, you might thing they are related somehow and create common ancestor for them, that will encapsulate this one instance for them.

Answer (score 1):

It's bad to assume something is universally bad. In your case, maybe it would be a good idea, but given that you're using a language that's not OO at the core it's more appropriate probably to just use loose methods and variables and put them in a common library that you include in your other work.